# Constant growth rate?

Tags: exponential-function

Say the population of a city is increasing at a constant rate of 11.5% per year. If the population is currently 2000, estimate how long it will take for the population to reach 3000.

Using the formula given, so far I've figured out how many years it will take (see working below) but how can I narrow it down to the nearest month?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you learned anything about logarithms yet?

Comment: Nope, not up to that yet.

Comment: You could use the same reasoning with $e^{12r}=1.115$ instead, and $x$ is the time in months. But this is quite tedious, and I would recommend you to read up on the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) instead, because you would get an exact solution much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=1.115^{1/12}=\sqrt[12]{1.115}$, the twelfth root of $1.115$. Then

$$1.115^x=(a^{12})^x=a^{12x}\;,$$

and $12x$ is the number of **months** that have gone by. Thus, if you can solve $a^y=1.5$, $y$ will be the desired number of months. Without logarithms the best that you’ll be able to do is find the smallest integer $y$ such that $a^y\ge 1.5$.

By my calculation $a\approx1.009112468437$. You could start with $a^{36}$ and work up until you find the desired $y$.

Comment: Nice explanation. I get 3 years and 9 months, is that right?

Comment: @jaykirby: I believe that you’re one month short: for $3$ years, $8$ months I get about $1.4905$, while for $3$ years, $9$ months I get about $1.5041$.

Comment: Noted. I amended my comment after realising that.

Comment: @jaykirby: Looks good, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same principle as in my previous solution. What you need is the growth rate in a month. Call the rate per month $e^s$, then

$$(e^s)^{12}=e^r=1.115$$

because after 12 months you of course have 1 year. You can solve this to give you

$$e^s=\sqrt[12]{1.115}=1.009112$$

You can work it out from here.

Comment: Got it. So if the monthly growth rate is 1.009112, what is the next step to figure out how many months total to reach 3000 people?

Comment: Follow the same steps of the previous exercise.